# postges: psql csv import fails although file exists

Tags: postgresql, import, psql, csv

Trying to import a `csv` file as follows:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d jira_statistics -U admin -p 5432 -c "COPY bugs FROM '/home/centos/bugs.csv' delimiter '|' csv;"
Password for user admin: 
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/centos/bugs.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

However both the file **and** the table exist in `jira_statistics` db

```
[root@jira-statistics ~]# ls /home/centos/bugs.csv
/home/centos/bugs.csv


[root@jira-statistics ~]# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U admin jira_statistics
Password for user admin: 
psql (9.2.24, server 11.1 (Debian 11.1-3.pgdg90+1))
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 11.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

jira_statistics=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------+-------+-------
 public | bugs     | table | admin
 public | devtasks | table | admin
 public | releases | table | admin
 public | stories  | table | admin
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for COPY failing is what is suggested in the hint, but then the error is a "Permission denied".

Since you get "No such file or directory", and a simple `ls` shows that the file exists, there are first a few plausible explanations that you want to check:

1. `/home/centos/bugs.csv` is a **soft link pointing to an non-existing file**. Use `ls -l` to be sure an check the destination if it's a soft link.
2. `127.0.0.1:5432` is redirected at the network level to a different machine. This technique is widely used to connect to remote services through **SSH tunnels**.
3. Your OS uses fancy security/isolation features that forbids `postgres` to read `/home/centos/bugs.csv` without issuing a *Permission denied* error. Try `ls -l /home/centos/bugs.csv` under the `postgres` OS account.
4. Your server and client don't run under the same [**MOUNT namespace**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html), due to [containerization](https://blog.selectel.com/containerization-mechanisms-namespaces/).

In cases #2 #3 or #4, just use `\copy` as suggested in the HINT part of the error message.

Comment: I am on `Centos7`, i disabled `SELINUX` and changed the file to `777` but still the same error.

Comment: I also moved the file to `/tmp/bugs.csv` so that the entire path is `777`

Comment: About being on CentOS: the signature of your server is `server 11.1 (Debian 11.1-3.pgdg90+1)` which tends to show that the postgres service is on a different machine running Debian. See my point #2

Comment: Yes `postgres` is containerized. However I am running the `psql` command from host, that's why I tried disabling `selinux` and `chmod`ded to `777`

Comment: @pkaramol: containerization explains it. The server and client filesystems are insulated from each other with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

This could be either a database permissions issue, a filesystem permissions issue, or perhaps an issue with the file's encoding type. (It could also be none of the above). Here are my suggestions:

For database permissions: only a superuser or a specifically-roled user can use COPY. See the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) on the COPY command:

> COPY naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers or users who are granted one of the default roles pg_read_server_files, pg_write_server_files, or pg_execute_server_program, since it allows reading or writing any file or running a program that the server has privileges to access.

For filesystem permissions: check that the service has read permission on the file.